DLL load failed while importing win32crypt
When I try to import win32crypt, I immediately get the following error:
builtins.ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32crypt: The specified procedure could not be found.
This link appears to be the same issue, but the solution here doesn't work:
Can't import win32crypt
It suggests changing "import win32crypt" to "from win32 import win32crypt", and in my case that results in the same error.
At first blush, this may also appear to be similar to this issue:
How to fix "ImportError: DLL load failed" while importing win32api
but this involves a different package.
It also suggests moving dll's into the c:\windows\system32 and I'm not sure that's safe.
In hopes of fixing the issue, at the Anaconda prompt, I typed: conda update win32crypt
and got back:
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
prefix: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
package name: win32crypt
Then I tried:
conda install win32crypt
and got back:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:  - win32crypt
So I surmise it must be part of some other package. After a search, I found files with win32crypt as part of their names in the pywin32 directory in site-packages. So I tried the following:
conda install pywin32
and got back "All requested packages installed"
I also tried: conda update pywin32
and got the following results:
Updating pywin32 is constricted by anaconda -> requires pywin32==302=py39h2bbff1b_2
If you are sure you want an update of your package either try conda update --all or install a specific version of the package you want using conda install <pkg>=<version>
done All requested packages already installed.
Then I tried updating with the --all option as suggested above, and got back a long and very scary looking list of packages that will "be superseded by a higher-priority channel". When asked to proceed I indicated No because I didn't want to chance breaking something that was still working.
I thought about uninstalling pywin32 in order to reinstall it, but that generated a long, scary list of packages that would be removed, so I didn't do that either.
Information about my system:
Windows Server 2022 Standard
Python 3.9.13
Anaconda version 22.9.0
Flask 1.1.2
So how do I get the win32crypt module to work? Do I need to install a specific version of pywin32?
I would like to avoid reinstalling Anaconda, if possible, because I'm concerned that will break a Flask application I have written.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Several days after my original post, I bit the bullet and reinstalled Anaconda, and even that didn't fix the problem. I'm still getting the same error when I try to import win32crypt.
